# RAILS I18n: How to use @ in translation key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Here is in our yml file:

```
Or make up unique one like login@a.com : 'test'
```

But here is the error on view page for `I18n.t("Or make up unique one like login@a.com")`:

```
translation missing: zh-CN.Or make up unique one like login@a.com
```

What causes the missing translation of t()?

UPDATE:

Just verified that the problem was caused by @ sign. Now the question becomes how to use @ in translation key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend the [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for beginners.

It will help you understand how to structure your files, how to setup routes to support a locale param, how to set the locale, and other useful tips.

---

The `t` helper is not intended to take a string of text to translate. It takes a yaml key and outputs the translated text from a locale file.

You want to structure your yaml file as such:

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  some_key: hello world
```

**config/locales/cn.yml**

```
cn:
  some_key: hello in Chinese
```

Then using it in your views

```
<%= t :some_key %>
```

Based on the `I18n.locale` setting, the `t` helper will look up `:some_key` in the corresponding locale file and output the translated text.

Comment: Our problem is the key was not recognized by t helper. We have the similar structure and all other keys are working except the one above. We are trying to find out why only this key is not recognizable.